# What kind of waves are these?

Tags: pwm, signal, serial, oscilloscope, waveform

Ok, please bear with me I am relatively new to the electronics scene.

I am trying to reverse engineer a pump controller.  Basically there is a switch that connects 12v to the pump to make it run and a lead that is connected to some kind of processor and a GPS that will increase the flow rate of the pump as the GPS detects a faster speed. I am trying to figure out how the second lead communicates with the flow regulator.

I was assuming from research that a simple pwm signal would be used to control the pump's output but that does not seem to be the case after connecting an oscilloscope to it.

Can anyone tell me what kind of a signal this wave may be so that I can research it?

[image]

Also, not sure if it is the oscilloscope (it's new for me) auto scaling or something else, but the pattern will slowly scale down in size over time.

Comment: Where is zero voltage level on the scope? Two divisions up from bottom?

Comment: Can you give some kind of diagram and indicate where and how you measure? It might be a PWM signal but distorted due to a capacitor somewhere in your measureing circuit.

Comment: yes, zero voltage is two divisions from bottom

Comment: The oscope is connected to the specific output lead that connects to the variable pump control wire. The ground is connected to the control box's ground.  There is no circuitry added.  I do like the idea you had about a capacitor being added to a pwm though.  Why would that be done?

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTtWkc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the basic schematic of a solenoid pump except it has very little mass and produces a triangle wave.  Somehow...gating off the recoil and back EMF you can get a quasi ramp wave with dead band.

The H sweep on a scope is somewhat similar except the retrace is much smaller and symmetrical with a linear bipolar ramp from the flyback transformer.

[**Here**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+0+2e-10+18.278915558614752+50+5+50%0AR+160+80+128+80+0+2+1000000+10+0+0+0.5%0Ar+160+80+208+80+0+25%0Af+208+80+272+80+0+1+0.02%0AR+272+64+272+16+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0AR+272+192+272+224+0+0+40+-5+0+0+0.5%0Af+208+144+272+144+1+1+0.02%0Aw+272+160+272+192+0%0Aw+208+80+208+144+0%0Aw+272+96+272+112+0%0Aw+272+112+336+112+0%0Ac+336+112+336+144+0+0.00001+0.0001450669667883986%0Al+336+144+336+192+0+0.000029999999999999997+-0.03464369997329765%0Ag+336+192+336+224+0%0Aw+272+112+272+128+0%0Ao+8+64+0+2337+3.57986298980937+0.07159725979618742+0+-1+0%0Ao+13+64+0+2337+4.091738259870177+0.08183476519740356+0+-1+0%0Ao+0+64+0+2083+18.707220957835556+9.765625e-55+1+-1+0%0Ao+9+64+0+2082+10+0.025+1+-1+0%0A) is how I synthesized your waveform.

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution, I really appreciate the time taken to simulate this.  Is it possible to have back emf when the pump isn't even connected to the controller though? Because I never connected the controller to the pump when taking the readings from the oscope.

Comment: BEMF is caused by inductive kickback and/or velocity of mag. field